# Open URL on a specific tab irrespective of any type of browser Java

Tags: java

Hi I have a java program. I have tried to mimic my actual program with a sample code below for my requirement:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

class SimpleTableExample extends JFrame
{

private JPanel pMainMenu = null;
public SimpleTableExample()
{

    pMainMenu = new JPanel();
    BorderLayout thisLayout = new BorderLayout();
    pMainMenu.setLayout(thisLayout);
    {
        JPanel pButtons = new JPanel();
        pMainMenu.add(pButtons, BorderLayout.NORTH);


            JButton btNew = new JButton();
            pButtons.add(btNew, new GridBagConstraints(2, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                    new Insets(0, 5, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            btNew.setText("<html><center>Open</center><center>urls</center></html>");
            btNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    btRunConfiguration(evt);
                }
            });

    }

    getContentPane().add(pMainMenu);
    getContentPane().repaint();
    pack();
    setSize(520, 130);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);


}

private void btRunConfiguration(ActionEvent evt) {
    getContentPane().removeAll();

    for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        try {
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
            String url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
            desktop.browse(new URI(url));
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException le) {
            le.printStackTrace();
        } catch(URISyntaxException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    }


}

public static void main( String args[] )
{
    SimpleTableExample mainFrame    = new SimpleTableExample();
    mainFrame.setVisible( true );
}



}
```

It opens few urls in a loop. Say, I have 5 different URLS which open in 5 different tabs. Here in sample program I am using a same url, but in my actual program they are different.
---for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
It reopens again the same urls in an outer loop. 
---for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
I would like to reopen those 5 urls in the same tabs again which they are currently open in. Basically those urls are google maps in actual program which change every few seconds.

Can anyone please help. Thanks. Appreciate it.